# Convert a number to a string to use in plot axes label, but keep the exponent

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, labeling

This seems to be a simple, but useful question.

I am plotting a basic function:

```
multiplier = 10^11;
func = 10^-11 x^2;
Plot[func*multiplier, {x, 0, 5}, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, "Distance, \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-11\)]\) m"}]
```

That gives the result I wish to see.

Imagine now that I wish not to write the multiplier manually in `AxesLabel` when I change it. The inverse multiplier needs to be converted to a string with an exponent (so as to produce the same final appearance). I have tried the `ToString` function with some parameters. For example:

```
multiplier = 10^11;
func = 10^-11 x^2;
Plot[func*multiplier, {x, 0, 5}, 
  AxesLabel -> 
    {x, "Distance, " <> ToString[multiplier^(-1), FormatType -> StandardForm] <> " m"}]
```

But I get an awful label.

1. Could you think of a solution to this problem?
2. Can anyone think of why conversion to real numbers by "N" is necessary and if not how can it be avoided?

Comment: Perhaps `"Distance, " <> ToString[N[multiplier^(-1)]` can be acceptable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You needn't mess around with string manipulation. It can also be done with `Row`.

```
multiplier = 10.^11;
func = 10.^-11 x^2;
yScale = ScientificForm[1/multiplier, NumberFormat -> (10^#3 &)];
Plot[func*multiplier, {x, 0, 5}, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, Row[{"Distance, ", yScale, " m"}, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial"}]}]
```

[image: plot.png]

Comment: @Nasser Great. It is true that it is easier to use spaces, than Spacer[]. At the same time your yScale definition will not work for you seem to need "N" function, although theoretically it does not seem to be necessary.

Comment: @Szczypawka. Sorry, but don't understand why I need `N` in `yScale`. The plot I show in my answer, which was made with my code, shows the correct axis label without using `N`.

Comment: That's true, but just because `N` is hidden in your code. If you look at your code and at the other answer, you will notice that your equivalent of `N` is defining multiplier and func initially as real numbers by saying `10.^11`, and what I am curious about is that theoretically one doesn't need such conversion.

Comment: @Szczypawka. I wouldn't say `N` is hidden in my code. I just choose to work with machine real numbers right from the start. It is more efficient, especially when plotting. Further, `ScientificForm` is designed to work on numbers with head Real. If you insist on the constraint that inexact numbers must be avoided in answers to your question, then my answer is simply bad. But I say such a constraint would be silly when the goal is to make a plot.

Comment: Thank you for the opinion. I don't insist that use of `N` is hidden in your code, and I understand well your desire to work with real numbers. And your answer is good. I use it in my code now.
But you see, ideally I multiply my data by `10^11` and not `10.^11`, you know, it is mathematically more precise, and I still think that it is very strange that I cannot directly put a natural number there without converting to real ones.
But I appreciate your working answer anyway, because it works. :)

Answer (score 3):

Possibly something like the following:

```
multiplier = 10^11;
func = 10^-11 x^2;
ylabel = ScientificForm[N@multiplier^(-1), NumberFormat -> (10^#3 &)];

Plot[func*multiplier, {x, 0, 5}, 
    AxesLabel -> {x,"Distance, " <> ToString[ylabel, FormatType ->
    StandardForm] <> " m"}]
```

[image]

This uses ScientificForm and the option NumberFormat to control the appearance.

Comment: A good solution, thank you.
It seems nevertheless, that "ScientificForm" is not the only possible option in the third string: "NumberForm" works also well.
The only doubtful point is that one needs convertion to approximate numbers by "N" which theoretically does not seem to be necessary. But the code would not work without it.

Comment: @Nasser That's true, great: the ToString is not needed. Still the question of using "N" stays.