# Show scientific form number in Epilog on a plot

Tags: graphics, output-formatting, text

I'd like to overlay a scientific form number on a `ListPlot` at a particular position.

Simply using `Text[ToString@value, {xpos,ypos}]` separates the exponent from the number and increases the font size. I found several posts about exponential notation for axes labels etc but I've not found one for this. I think one way would be to somehow convert the `ScientificForm` object into a `Graphics` object, then I could place it anywhere.

I think this must be a duplicate question as it seems so fundamental but I'm clearly searching for the wrong expressions!

Comment: Note that an `Inset` does not need to be a `Graphics`.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29497/convert-a-number-to-a-string-to-use-in-plot-axes-label-but-keep-the-exponent/29500#29500)?

Comment: Thank you MarcoB! Inset is exactly what I needed.
    Inset[value,Scaled[{xpos,ypos}]];

Comment: As an example, you could use `Epilog -> 
 Inset[Style[ScientificForm[N@value], Red, FontSize -> 14], 
  Scaled[{xpos, ypos}]]` to have control over the color, font size, positions, etc. of the text you want overlaid.

Comment: @march. That's not a good coding example. The use of string operations in generating the label is totally unnecessary. One can just use `Row`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Text` graphics primitive to place a `ScientificForm` expression anywhere in a graphics pane without resorting to string conversion. For example,

```
Graphics[{
  Circle[], 
  Text[Style[ScientificForm[N[Pi 1*^10], 8], 14, Bold, Red], Scaled @ {.5, .9}]}]
```

produces

[image: circle]

I didn't bother to introduce `Epilog` here, but `Text` expression like this one are perfectly acceptable in a list of graphic primitives given to `Epilog`.